# How to add php sql to wordpress environment

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, select

I have a problem. This my php code and its worked well. But how to convert this code WordPress environment based. I saw WordPress select SQL but I can't understand that. please help me. Anyone can rewrite this code on WordPress environment.
Thanks

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "submit-form");  
 if(isset($_POST["query"]))  
 {  
      $output = '';  
      $query = "SELECT * FROM search_content WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
      $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">';  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '<li><strong>'.$row["Name"].',</strong> <span class="continent"> '.$row["Continent"].',</span>';  
           }  
      }  
      else  
      {  
           $output .= '<li>Country Not Found</li>';  
      }  
      $output .= '</ul>';  
      echo $output;  
 }
```

Comment: use like this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/110682/111751

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
<?php  
 global $wpdb;

    if(isset($_POST["query"]))  
        { 
        $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM search_content WHERE Name LIKE '%".$_POST["query"]."%'");
        $output = '';  
        $output = '<ul class="list-unstyled">'; 

        if(count($result) > 0)  
        {

            foreach ( $result as $row )
            {
            $output .= '<li><strong>'.$row->Name.',</strong> <span class="continent"> '.$row->Continent.',</span>'; 
            }  
        }  
        else  
        {  
           $output .= '<li>Country Not Found</li>';  
        } 

      $output .= '</ul>';  
      echo $output;  
 } 
 ?>
```